# counting up to 100

Tags: recreational-mathematics

I have one question if someone could help me how to calculate it: If I have some amount of money (Euros). What the amount I have if I need to have the amount once doubled plus a half of the amount plus a quarter of the amount plus 1 to have 100 Euros?

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Your question is a bit unclear. I'm not quite sure what you're asking. Also, to get more help, do put in some context including where you found the question. Also, please also include what you've tried as it shows that you're engaged in finding the solution! Kindly edit your post!

Comment: Hello and thanks. This is a quiz question and I wonder how to calculate it right. I get the exact result but wonder what would be a more convenient way to get he result. This is how i got it. (36+36+(36/2)+(36/4)+1)=100 So the amount I currently have is 36 but this is just a calculation if you know the amount of Euros in advance, but i wonder how to calculate it with a guess that we don't know it?

So to make it more clear once more: I have some amount of Euros. What's the amount if have have to add the same amount once more + a half of the amount + a quarter of it + 1?

Comment: Please edit your question instead of asking it again. The information you provided is very useful and definitely belongs in [your newer question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4115236/solve-xx-fracx2-fracx41-100).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose we have some amount of money, we call this $x$. Then, based on you question, we want
$$x+x+\frac{x}2+\frac{x}{4}+1=100.$$
Simplifying yields
$$\frac{11x}{4}=99.$$
Then
$$x=\frac{99\cdot 4}{11}=36.$$

Comment: Thank you! But how do you get 11x/4=99?